# Research topics about non Euclidian geometry?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The title pretty much sums it up. I am wondering if anyone has some interesting research topics to investigate about non-euclidian geometry?

Sorry for the confusion, I am a first year undergrad, so something like riemannian geometry with like manifold seems out of my math capabilities. I know this area is already "dead", I just need to write a 4000 paper about it.

Comment: This question seems incredibly broad. Basically all Riemannian geometry is about non-Euclidean geometry, it is a whole field with hundreds of active researchers and hundreds of questions. Maybe you could say a little more about what you seek, for what purpose, to make the question answerable, but in any case it might still be deemed unsuitable for MO.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner If geometry is not euclidean, it does not mean that it is non-euclidean. For example, Riemannian geometry is not considered to be non-euclidian.

Comment: You made wrong tags to the question, so it is misunderstood by many.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin then terminology differs between people: I do consider Riemannian geometry as non-Euclidean. Do you restrict the word to constant curvature? To homogeneous spaces? In any case, the question cannot really be answered as is.

Comment: @BenoîtKloeckner in the standard terminology is non-euclidean geometry is a geometry that like euclidean, but not euclidean.

Comment: *I am a first year undergrad* --- Your use of "research topic" is probably different than what is commonly understood here, as I suspect what you are to do is to learn about some topic and write an extended essay on it. Maybe something suitable can be found in [**Non-Euclidean Geometry**](https://archive.org/details/noneuclideangeom00mann) by Manning (1901; reprinted with title change by Dover Publications in 1963). Also you might want to look through [**Bibliography of Non-Euclidean Geometry**](https://archive.org/details/bibliographyofno00sommuoft) by Sommerville (1911), **(continued)**

Comment: although the vast majority of the items in that bibliography will not be appropriate, but a handful of the later publications might be appropriate (being elementary expositions). Pretty much anything listed there is probably freely available online at google-books (just google the title, sometimes without using quotes due to .pdf character misreads; sometimes restricting the search to plus/minus two or three years of the publication date works better). [Also, these *Mathematics Teachers* articles](https://web.archive.org/web/20050405082941/http://mathforum.org/mathed/mtbib/non.euclidean.html).